# Auto adjust the height for full width image filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, autoresize

I have amended the code from [here](http://oinutter.co.uk/guggenheim.js), so that the images can be displayed in full width. But I'm facing one issue, which the height cannot auto resize on different screen size.

You can resize the browser window to produce more outputs. If you do so, you will see there is a big gap between the images and the `"testing"` text. The gap is causing by the code `height:117vh`. My problem is here.

I have no idea how to amend the code for auto adjust the height, and I used CSS to replace it, which is not a good solution. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks.

```js
function filterEls(category){
  gallery.filter(category)
};

$('.filter-bt').click(function(){
  $('.filter-bt.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current'); 

});

window.onload = function(){ 
  gallery = guggenheim('#basic-gallery')
};


//Refresh page on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() > 1000){ 
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () { 
      "use strict";
      window.location.reload(); 
    });
  } 
});
```

```css
.gallery{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  height:117vh; 
  /*text-align:center;*/
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.works-tab-filter{
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}

.works-tab-filter a{
  padding: 0 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaa;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.buttons a.prev, .buttons a.next{
  position:absolute;
  top:46%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.buttons a.prev{ left:0; background: #000; }
.buttons a.next{ right:0; background: #000; }

.buttons a.prev, .buttons a.next{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 43px; 
  height: 72px; 
 }

.guggenheim-item{
  width:25%;
  padding:0;
  margin: -2px 0;
}
 
.sprite {width:100%; display: inline-block; }
.sprite img{width:100%; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1049px){
 .gallery{
  width:100%;
  height:145vh;
  padding: 0 2%;
 }
 
 .guggenheim-item{
  width:48%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .gallery{
  width:100%;
  height:200vh;
  padding: 0 2%;
 }
 
 .guggenheim-item{
  width:90%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://oinutter.co.uk/guggenheim.js/js/guggenheim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="works-tab-filter col-md-4 wp2 delay-105s">
 <a class="filter-bt current" onclick='filterEls("")'>All</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("campaign")'>Campaign</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("identity")'>Identity</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("interactive")'>Interactive</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("prints")'>Prints</a>
</div>
 
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="basic-gallery" class="gallery col-md-4 wp2 delay-2s">
 <div class="buttons"> <!-- Hide button when only one page -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="gallery.prev()"></a>
  <a class="next" onclick="gallery.next()"></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="guggenheim-slider">
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
      <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
        <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div>testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my source and tested it. Its working now. Please test and let me know if you need any further help

```js
function filterEls(category){
  gallery.filter(category)
};

$('.filter-bt').click(function(){
  $('.filter-bt.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current'); 

});

window.onload = function(){ 
  gallery = guggenheim('#basic-gallery')
};


//Refresh page on resize
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() > 1000){ 
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () { 
      "use strict";
      window.location.reload(); 
    });
  } 
});
```

```css
.gallery{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  height:calc(100%); 
  /*text-align:center;*/
  position:absolute !important;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.works-tab-filter{
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}

.works-tab-filter a{
  padding: 0 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaa;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.buttons a.prev, .buttons a.next{
  position:absolute;
  top:46%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.buttons a.prev{ left:0; background: #000; }
.buttons a.next{ right:0; background: #000; }

.buttons a.prev, .buttons a.next{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 43px; 
  height: 72px; 
 }

.guggenheim-item{
  width:25%;
  padding:0;
  margin: -2px 0;
}
 
.sprite {width:100%; display: inline-block; }
.sprite img{width:100%; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1049px){
 .gallery{
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100%);
  padding: 0 2%;
 }
 
 .guggenheim-item{
  width:48%;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .gallery{
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100%);
  padding: 0 2%;
 }
 
 .guggenheim-item{
  width:90%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://oinutter.co.uk/guggenheim.js/js/guggenheim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="works-tab-filter col-md-4 wp2 delay-105s">
 <a class="filter-bt current" onclick='filterEls("")'>All</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("campaign")'>Campaign</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("identity")'>Identity</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("interactive")'>Interactive</a>
 <a class="filter-bt" onclick='filterEls("prints")'>Prints</a>
</div>
 
<br/>
<br/>

<div id="basic-gallery" class="gallery col-md-4 wp2 delay-2s" style="padding:0">
 <div class="buttons"> <!-- Hide button when only one page -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="gallery.prev()"></a>
  <a class="next" onclick="gallery.next()"></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="guggenheim-slider">
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
      <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
        <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/kzuwbknzp/aa_05.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/e462eq451/aa_01.jpg"  />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/i1tc44qyd/aa_02.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item campaign prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/5ol3ayqnp/aa_03.jpg" />
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="guggenheim-item identity prints">
   <span class="sprite">
    <img src="https://s18.postimg.org/fn61xg039/aa_04.jpg"/>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">testing</div>
```

Comment: no, cannot. When I removed the code, the images will not showing.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I have written some js to update height of gallery element to have full height.

Comment: there is no gap but the images are cropped

Comment: Please check updated code. I tried to remove the space. there are some css fixes that may be you need to do

Comment: I can't put `fixed and bottom 0` because my code is used for one page scrolling.

Comment: oh, Then you have to find some other way to make this content in the bottom of the screen